# axis1.0 change character set encoding

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I am using axis1.0 as the client for interfacing with a web service. Is there a way to change the character set encoding on the Soap requests.

All the requests are currently going with encoding="UTF-8". I want to change the same to ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Here is the response which is causing a problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns0:RespServiceEnvelope xmlns:ns0="http://cititech.citi.com/imass/services/ContentService/ServiceEnvelope/response/schema/1.0"><ns0:RespServiceHeader><ns1:MsgIdentifier xmlns:ns1="http://cititech.citi.com/imass/services/common/CommonSchemas/schema/1.0"><ns1:MsgName>CitiDirect</ns1:MsgName><ns1:MsgVersion>1.0</ns1:MsgVersion><ns1:CreDtTm>2015-05-06T12:15:05.096-04:00</ns1:CreDtTm></ns1:MsgIdentifier><ns1:RespondingApp xmlns:ns1="http://cititech.citi.com/imass/services/common/CommonSchemas/schema/1.0"><ns1:CorrelationID>CitiDirect</ns1:CorrelationID><ns1:ProcessingSrvr>gtstibtxd3.nam.nsroot.net</ns1:ProcessingSrvr><ns1:RespProcId>26192</ns1:RespProcId></ns1:RespondingApp></ns0:RespServiceHeader><ns0:RespServiceBody><ns1:getDcmntLstResp xmlns:ns1="http://cititech.citi.com/imass/services/ContentService/schema/1.0"><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>DITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.7326E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>EITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>2</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.398E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>DITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.7326E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>EITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>2</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.398E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>DITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.7326E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>EITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>2</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.398E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>CITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE FOLHA DE PAGAMENTO</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST102</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.2812E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>CITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE FOLHA DE PAGAMENTO</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST102</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>djcxMjYtMTcwMDItMTcwMDMtMTcwMDctR1VCMS04N0ZBQUEtMjI4MTItMjE2MjItMC02OTMwLTg1LTc5LTItNC0wLV4BMTY1MzUBU1QxMDIBUkVMQVTTUklPIENPTlNPTElEQURPIERFIEZPTEhBIERFIFBBR0FNRU5UTwFXRUVLTFkBU1RBVEVNRU5UAVBBWVJPTEwBMTIzNDU2Nzg5MgExMjM0NTY3ODkzATEyMzQ1Njc4OTEBQUExMjM0NTY3ODkwAUNJVElCQU5LIExFQVNJTkcgUy9BIEFSUkVOREFNRU5UTyBNRVJDQU5USUxYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFgBMTIuMzQ1LjY3OC8wMDAxLTM0ATEyMwFYRVJFTVhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWAFCUgFCUkFTSUxYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYATExMjYzNzcyNzkBMTM0MDc3Mzc3MwE1NTY2NzcyMjk5ATIBMTQzMDE1OTQ0NQFUVFNfUGF5bWVudF9TVE1UICAgICAgICAgICAgICABR1VCLTA1Rjc3RUEzMkNEQjQ1QjdBOTAxNjY1NTYwRjA2MTREATABMjE2MjI=</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>2</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.1622E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>DITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.7326E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>EITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>2</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.398E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>DITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.7326E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>EITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>2</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.398E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>CITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>djcxMjYtMTcwMDItMTcwMDMtMTcwMDctR1VCMS04NkZBQUEtMC0zNDU5NC0wLTk5MTctODUtNzktMi00LTAtXgExNjUzNQFTVDEwMQFSRUxBVNNSSU8gQ09OU09MSURBRE8gREUgUEFHQU1FTlRPUwFXRUVLTFkBU1RBVEVNRU5UAVBBWVJPTEwBMTIzNDU2Nzg5MgExMjM0NTY3ODkzATEyMzQ1Njc4OTEBQUE5OTEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MAFDSVRJQkFOSyBMRUFTSU5HIFMvQSBBUlJFTkRBTUVOVE8gTUVSQ0FOVElMWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYATEyLjM0NS42NzgvMDAwMS0zNAExMjMBWEVSRU1YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFgBQlIBQlJBU0lMWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWAExMTI2Mzc3Mjc5ATEzNDA3NzM3NzMBNTU2Njc3MjI5OQE0ATE0MzAxNTk0NDQBVFRTX1BheW1lbnRfU1RNVCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgAUdVQi01RURCMTVGOTk4NUE0RTlFQkMxMkM4NkVFOEIwQzM2OAEwATM0NTk0</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>4</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>3.4594E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>CITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>djcxMjYtMTcwMDItMTcwMDMtMTcwMDctR1VCMS04NkZBQUEtMzQ1OTQtMjczMjYtMC05OTE3LTg1LTc5LTItNC0wLV4BMTY1MzUBU1QxMDEBUkVMQVTTUklPIENPTlNPTElEQURPIERFIFBBR0FNRU5UT1MBV0VFS0xZAVNUQVRFTUVOVAFQQVlST0xMATEyMzQ1Njc4OTIBMTIzNDU2Nzg5MwExMjM0NTY3ODkxAUFBMTIzNDU2Nzg5MAFDSVRJQkFOSyBMRUFTSU5HIFMvQSBBUlJFTkRBTUVOVE8gTUVSQ0FOVElMWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYATEyLjM0NS42NzgvMDAwMS0zNAExMjMBWEVSRU1YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFgBQlIBQlJBU0lMWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWAExMTI2Mzc3Mjc5ATEzNDA3NzM3NzMBNTU2Njc3MjI5OQEzATE0MzAxNTk0NDQBVFRTX1BheW1lbnRfU1RNVCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgAUdVQi0xNTgxQUY0OUMxRTQ0OUJBODkwRDJBRUNGNkU4MDBBOQEwATI3MzI2</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.7326E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>DITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.7326E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>EITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>2</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.398E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>DITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.7326E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>EITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>2</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.398E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>DITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>3</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.7326E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:Document><ns1:CstmrNm>EITIBANK LEASING S/A ARRENDAMENTO MERCANTILXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns1:CstmrNm><ns1:CstmrTaxId>12.345.678/0001-34</ns1:CstmrTaxId><ns1:AcctNbr>1234567893</ns1:AcctNbr><ns1:RptDt>2015-04-09</ns1:RptDt><ns1:RptNm>RELATÓRIO CONSOLIDADO DE PAGAMENTOS</ns1:RptNm><ns1:RptTp>STATEMENT</ns1:RptTp><ns1:RptSubTp>ST101</ns1:RptSubTp><ns1:Frqcy>WEEKLY</ns1:Frqcy><ns1:PdctCd>PAYROLL</ns1:PdctCd><ns1:LclBrnchCd>123</ns1:LclBrnchCd><ns1:DcmntMtDt><ns1:DcmntId>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</ns1:DcmntId><ns1:MimeTp>application/afp</ns1:MimeTp><ns1:NbrPgs>2</ns1:NbrPgs><ns1:DcmntSz>2.398E4</ns1:DcmntSz></ns1:DcmntMtDt></ns1:Document><ns1:PgDtls><ns2:CurNtries xmlns:ns2="http://cititech.citi.com/imass/services/common/CommonSchemas/schema/1.0">20</ns2:CurNtries><ns2:TtlNtries xmlns:ns2="http://cititech.citi.com/imass/services/common/CommonSchemas/schema/1.0">20</ns2:TtlNtries><ns2:MorePgInd xmlns:ns2="http://cititech.citi.com/imass/services/common/CommonSchemas/schema/1.0">false</ns2:MorePgInd></ns1:PgDtls></ns1:getDcmntLstResp><ns0:ServiceStatus><ns1:OperationStatus status="SUCCESS" xmlns:ns1="http://cititech.citi.com/imass/services/common/CommonSchemas/schema/1.0">REQUEST IS SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED</ns1:OperationStatus></ns0:ServiceStatus></ns0:RespServiceBody></ns0:RespServiceEnvelope></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Below is the exception trace:

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}Server.userException
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
 faultActor: null
 faultDetail: 
    stackTrace: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onStartChild(SimpleDeserializer.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContextImpl.startElement(DeserializationContextImpl.java:893)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:200)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:684)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:241)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:265)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1871)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1777)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1315)
```

When I opened the response in firefox, it says bad xml, after changing the encoding="ISO-8859-1" it is able to parse correctly.

I do not have access to the server on which the web service is hosted.

Comment: Using UTF-8 is *usually* a much better bet than other encodings - can we ask *why* you'd want to use ISO-8859-1 instead? (In particular, that doesn't encode all of Unicode...)

Comment: Apparently, the response contains some Portuguese characters which dont gel well with UTF-8 and is causing SAXException while parsing.Somebody suggested to change the encoding on the request itself so that I get the response in ISO-8859-1  encoding.

Comment: No, that's nonsense - UTF-8 can handle *all* Unicode characters. Where exactly is the problem? What does the stack trace look like? Have you captured the details of a request, e.g. with Wireshark? Is the server one you run (and can fix if necessary)? All of this information should be in the question... it's very unclear at the moment whether the real problem is with the client or the server.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Apologies for the incomplete details.  Have updated the original post with the soap response and the exception stack trace that I am getting in apache axis.

Comment: So it's the *response* that's the problem, not the request? But your question says you want to change the *request* to UTF-8. You still haven't told us much about the server other than that you "do not have access" to it... which looks like it's where the problem is. Is that code from your company? Can you host a test version of it to experiment? Do you know what its web service stack is?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Exactly, response is the problem. Also, the web server is with a different company, hence I do not have access to it. As per their confirmation, they are sending the response in ISO-8859-1. Hence, I was looking for a way if this encoding can be set somewhere on the client side while sending the request itself and expect to get the response with the same encoding value which might solve the issue.  Also, I see that on higher versions of Apache Axis (I am tied to axis 1.0), I can set the same as CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING on the org.apache.axis.client.Call.setProperty,

Comment: Their response explicitly *states* it's in UTF-8. Basically, their code is broken, and should be fixed. You shouldn't be changing your code to workaround their brokenness.

Comment: I tried generating the stubs using apache axis 1.4 and it seems to work, all else being same. Seems it might be the way that axis 1.0 deserializes the response which is causing the exception.

Comment: No, the response you've shown clearly advertises itself as UTF-8. If it's not really UTF-8, that can't be a client bug. There may be client workarounds, but the server is broken and you should complain strongly.